# Spearmint Yield

Tags: vegetables, planting, container-gardening, greenhouse, tea

would any of you know approximately how much spearmint I could get per plant? I am looking to buy a four tier greenhouse and fill it up completely with spearmint so I am not exactly sure how much the yield would be.

Comment: Why are you proposing to grow a hardy perennial field plant in a greenhouse? What is your end product you want to know the yield of - leaves (green or dry?), oil? I can't imagine that "4 tiers" will work out well for 3 of them, as the top layer will block most of the light. to any below.

Comment: Mint really doesn't grow well in pots anyway, assuming that's what you're planning

Comment: I put my mint in a pot in the ground this year to keep the roots from spreading too much.Seems to have worked well; but I'm still pulling mint out of the bed it used to be in. It is mostly a weed that doesn't require much care and feeding; and it will grow as big as you allow it. I have cut mine one plant, propagated from one stem that survived last winter, back several times so it would not shadow other plants, and i still have plenty left to make jalapeno mint jelly when the peppers ripen.